# Help me to understand this c# code

Tags: c#

this code in [Beginning C# 3.0: An Introduction to Object Oriented Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470261293)

this is a program that has the user enter a couple of sentences in a multi - line textbox and then count how many times each letter occurs in that text

```
  private const int MAXLETTERS = 26;            // Symbolic constants
  private const int MAXCHARS = MAXLETTERS - 1;
  private const int LETTERA = 65;
```

.........

```
private void btnCalc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    char oneLetter;
    int index;
    int i;
    int length;
    int[] count = new int[MAXLETTERS];
    string input;
    string buff;

    length = txtInput.Text.Length;
    if (length == 0)    // Anything to count??
    {
      MessageBox.Show("You need to enter some text.", "Missing Input");
      txtInput.Focus();
      return;
    }
    input = txtInput.Text;
    input = input.ToUpper();


    for (i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)    // Examine all letters.
    {
      oneLetter = input[i];               // Get a character
      index = oneLetter - LETTERA;        // Make into an index
      if (index < 0 || index > MAXCHARS)  // A letter??
        continue;                         // Nope.
      count[index]++;                     // Yep.
    }

    for (i = 0; i < MAXLETTERS; i++)
    {
      buff = string.Format("{0, 4} {1,20}[{2}]", (char)(i + LETTERA)," ",count[i]);
      lstOutput.Items.Add(buff);
    }
  }
```

I do not understand this line

```
 count[index]++;
```

and this line of code

```
buff = string.Format("{0, 4} {1,20}[{2}]", (char)(i + LETTERA)," ",count[i]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
count[index]++;
```

That's a **post-increment**.  If you were to save the return of that it would be count[index] prior to the increment, but all it basically does is increment the value and return the value prior to the increment.  As for the reason why there is a variable inside square brackets, it is referencing a value in the index of an array.  In other words, if you wanted to talk about the fifth car on the street, you may consider something like StreetCars(5).  Well, in C# we use square brackets and zero-indexing, so we would have something like StreetCars[4].  If you had a Car array call StreetCars you could reference the 5th Car by using the indexed value.

As for the string.Format() method, check out [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Comment: To build on Surfer513's comment, count is an "array" of whole numbers. Array's are like cars on a train, each one holding a value. So, this code converts a character into its numeric equivalent, find's that position in the array and increases the count by 1, because the code is attempting to record letter frequency.

Comment: @billinkc, good call.  I assumed that the OP understood arrays.

Comment: I assume'd since they didn't question the i++ bit, it either "blended in" or it was the array bit.  Feel free to wrap any of that into your answer if you wish

Comment: @surfer513 thank you man .. Can you explain to me the meaning of   continue;

Comment: @tarek11011, yeah absolutely.  What 'continue' does is when executed it moves to the next iteration of the loop.  For instance, if you have continue that executes, even if it says Console.WriteLine("This will never execute"); after the continue, that WriteLine() method will not execute because when continue is reached, it goes to the next iteration of the loop.  Make sense?

Comment: @tarek11011, another one is 'break'.  If break is executed in a loop, no matter how many iterations are left or what's happening in the loop, if 'break' is executed the loop terminates right then and there.  So you use 'break' to exit a loop.  Just an FYI.

Comment: @surfer513 I do not know how to thank you ... Thank you very much

Comment: @tarek11011, not a problem at all.  Software development is a beautiful thing.  Stay passionate about it and before you know it you'll be doing some very amazing things with great code.

Answer (score 5):

`count[index]++;` means "add 1 to the value in `count` at index `index`".  The `++` is specifically known as *incrementing*.  What the code is doing is tallying the number of occurrences of a letter.

`buff = string.Format("{0, 4} {1,20}[{2}]", (char)(i + LETTERA)," ",count[i]);` is formatting a line of output.  With [string.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1csw23d.aspx), you first pass in a *format specifier* that works like a template or form letter.  The parts between `{` and `}` specify how the additional arguments passed into `string.Format` are used.  Let me break down the format specification:

```
{0, 4}       The first (index 0) argument (which is the letter, in this case).
             The ,4 part means that when it is output, it should occupy 4 columns
             of text.

{1,20}       The second (index 1) argument (which is a space in this case).
             The ,20 is used to force the output to be 20 spaces instead of 1.

{2}          The third (index 2) argument (which is the count, in this case).
```

So when `string.Format` runs, `(char)(i + LETTERA)` is used as the first argument and is plugged into the `{0}` portion of the format.  `" "` is plugged into `{1}`, and `count[i]` is plugged into `{2}`.